"Abelianicity" of the group of automophisms of the fundamental functor
Given a small Galois category $(C,F)$, are there axioms for $C$ and $F$ characterizing the "abelianicity" of $\operatorname{Aut}(F)$? I mean something like "$\operatorname{Aut}(F)$ is abelian iff ..."
I tried to find some references for this question but couldn't.
Any help is appreciated.

I think there ought to be something along the following lines, but I don't know how the details work out and I don't know if anyone has found it worthwhile to write anything like this down. A Galois category is some kind of incarnation of a profinite group $G$; more precisely it is some kind of "(locally constant) sheaves on $BG$" where $BG$ denotes the classifying space.
Now, algebraic topologists know that $BG$ has a special feature when $G$ is abelian: it is itself an abelian group, in a suitable sense (more precisely a grouplike $E_{\infty}$ space or connective spectrum). The converse is a version of the Eckmann-Hilton argument. A category-theoretic version of this is: if $G$ is a discrete group, then the one-object category $BG$ admits a monoidal structure iff $G$ is abelian (the converse here is exactly the Eckmann-Hilton argument). This boils down to the group-theoretic fact that the multiplication $G \times G \to G$ is itself a group homomorphism iff $G$ is abelian.
(There are some familiar examples where we can explicitly describe the multiplication $BG \times BG \to BG$ when $G$ is abelian. For example if $G = U(1)$ then $BU(1)$ is the classifying space of complex line bundles, and the multiplication is given by tensor product of line bundles.)
So, if $G$ (now the profinite group again) is abelian, the "abelian group" structure on $BG$ ought to be visible from the perspective of sheaves. More precisely the multiplication $BG \times BG \to BG$ ought to dualize to a "comultiplication"
$$\text{Sh}(BG) \to \text{Sh}(BG \times BG)$$
making $\text{Sh}(BG)$ into some kind of "symmetric comonoidal category," and then perhaps there should be a converse to this saying that $G$ is abelian iff $\text{Sh}(BG)$ admits a comultiplication of this sort.
The difficulty here is figuring out what the target of the comultiplication should be in terms of the Galois category alone. $\text{Sh}(BG \times BG)$ is not the cartesian product $\text{Sh}(BG) \times \text{Sh}(BG)$ (which would be $\text{Sh}(BG \sqcup BG)$), it is some kind of "tensor product," and I don't know what definition of tensor product does the right thing here.
